# How to remove duplicate elements from 2 lists and form a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists:

```
a=['Sensor', 'Sensor', 'Microphone', 'IFE0', 'IFE0', 'IFE0', 'IFE1', 
   'IFE1', 'IFE1', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU']
```

and another list which needs to be mapped to its elements.

```
b=['Source', 'Source', 'Source', 'Process', 'Process', 'Process', 'Process', 
   'Process', 'Process', 'Sink', 'Sink', 'Sink']
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary with key from list "a" mapped to values 
from "b". My output should look like

```
c={'Sensor': Source,'Microphone': Source,'IFE0': Process,'IFE1':Process,'GPU':Sink'}
```

How to filter duplicate elements on both the lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do **dict(zip(a, b))**

```
zip(a, b)
Output : [('Sensor', 'Source'),
 ('Sensor', 'Source'),
 ('Microphone', 'Source'),
 ('IFE0', 'Process'),
 ('IFE0', 'Process'),
 ('IFE0', 'Process'),
 ('IFE1', 'Process'),
 ('IFE1', 'Process'),
 ('IFE1', 'Process'),
 ('GPU', 'Sink'),
 ('GPU', 'Sink'),
 ('GPU', 'Sink')]
```

will map the similar index of both lists **a** and **b** (List of tuples).

Now converting it to **dict** will give you unique dictionary.

```
dict(zip(a, b))

output: {'GPU': 'Sink',
 'IFE0': 'Process',
 'IFE1': 'Process',
 'Microphone': 'Source',
 'Sensor': 'Source'}
```

Comment: how exactly does this add any new value compared to the posts given before?

Comment: @user3053452 if you can check edited history of that post you will get the answer

Answer (score 4):

you can directly produce a dictionary using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehensions#dictionaries):

```
c = {key: value for key, value in zip(a, b)}
```

or more directly using the `dict` constructor

```
c = dict(zip(a, b))
```

in order to get

```
{'Sensor': 'Source', 'Microphone': 'Source', 'IFE0': 'Process', 
 'IFE1': 'Process', 'GPU': 'Sink'}
```

---

`zip` iterates over the values of your lists in pairs:

```
for pairs in zip(a, b):
   print(pairs)
```

produces

```
('Sensor', 'Source')
('Sensor', 'Source')
('Microphone', 'Source')
('IFE0', 'Process')
('IFE0', 'Process')
('IFE0', 'Process')
('IFE1', 'Process')
('IFE1', 'Process')
('IFE1', 'Process')
('GPU', 'Sink')
('GPU', 'Sink')
('GPU', 'Sink')
```

these entries then get converted to a dictionary - mapping `key, value = pair`. the `dict` will then remove the duplicate `key`s; the version using the `dict` constructor does the same (just not that explicit).

Comment: Tried this,but 'zip' creates non-duplicate elements from 'a' list, but the 'b' list doesn't get mapped according,I'm getting{'Sensor': 'Source', 'Microphone': 'Source', 'IFE0': 'Source', 'IFE1': 'Process', 'GPU': 'Process....'}

Comment: no: `zip` does not care about duplicates. it is the `dict` that removes them. and the code prined above will not produce ` 'GPU': 'Process'`; have a look at the second part of the answer.

Comment: ('Sensor', 'Source')
('Microphone', 'Source')
('IFE0', 'Source')
('IFE1', 'Process')
('GPU', 'Process')
('IPE', 'Process')
('VENUS', 'Process')
('LPASS', 'Process')
('CPU ', 'Process')
('FD', 'Process')
('MDP', 'Process')
('FS', 'Process')
('Display', 'Process')

Comment: I'm getting the above output after the 'zip' pair........IFE0 is not Source...It should be mapped to Process

Comment: this is not the list you have posted. the list you are using is mismatchted then. `zip` iterates over both lists at the same pace.

Comment: Sorry,I got confused over the lists......The zip pair works perfectly.....Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
a=['Sensor', 'Sensor', 'Microphone', 'IFE0', 'IFE0', 'IFE0', 'IFE1', 
   'IFE1', 'IFE1', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU']
b=['Source', 'Source', 'Source', 'Process', 'Process', 'Process', 'Process', 
   'Process', 'Process', 'Sink', 'Sink', 'Sink']
c = dict(zip(a,b))
```

Comment: this will never result in more than one `'Source'`.

Answer (score -2):

Try zipping them first and then turning them into a set (to discard duplicates):

`c = list(set(zip(a, b)))`

Then turn that list into a dictionary as you wish:

```py
d = {}
for k, v in c:
    d[k] = v
```

Or just `d = dict(c)`

**Even simpler - `dict(zip(a,b))`**